# How to return an entity with chosen columns using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm really new with Hibernate. I want a `List<User>` using hibernate criteria, but only with fields User id and name filled up. Is that possible? Something like the query shown below:

```
SELECT user.id, user.name FROM user
```

Regards.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is exactly what projections are for.  Here is an example:

```
  Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class)
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("id"), "id")
      .add(Projections.property("Name"), "Name"))
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(User.class));

  List<User> list = cr.list();
```

In fact, if you look at the documentation for "lazy property fetching" they specifically say:

---

"A different (better?) way to avoid unnecessary column reads, at least for read-only transactions is to use the projection features of HQL or Criteria queries. This avoids the need for buildtime bytecode processing and is certainly a preferred solution."

---

By the way, there is a related question that you may also be interested in:
[Hibernate Query By Example and Projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84644/hibernate-query-by-example-and-projections)

Comment: Is it possible to do it via HQL querry?

Answer (score 3):

I'm really late answering this, but, you can add a custom result transformer to the Query object like below.

```
Query query = session
        .getNamedQuery(
                "someNamedQueryWhichISHQL")
        .setString("cod", "10")
        .setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {

            public Object transformTuple(Object[] row, String[] arg1) {
                User usr = new User(row[0],row[1]);
                return usr
            }

            public List transformList(List arg0) {

                return arg0;
            }
        });
return query.list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically you don't want to partially load the properties of an object. But if you must, see this:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties

For plain reporting-like behaviour you could use entity queries:

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, NAME, BIRTHDATE FROM CATS").addEntity(Cat.class);
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/manual/en-US/html/querysql.html#d0e17633