# How to prevent ClassCastException with JPA entities?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

I get a ClassCastException when trying to query my JPA entity class.  I only want json to show two columns.  That is name and address.  How do I only show selected columns in JPA?  From debugging it has to be the for loop. So List is the object and I need to make the right side an object instead of a list correct?

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Personnel")
public class User implements Serializable {

private String id;
private String name;
private String address;

public User(String id, String name, String address) 
{
this.id = id;
this.name = name;
this.address = address;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}....
 //setters getters
```

**Query/Impl**

```
public List<User> getRecords(User ent){

     String sql = "select "
                + " usr.name, usr.address "                 
                + " from User usr"           
                + " where usr.id = '1' ";

    List<User> records = this.getSession().createQuery(sql).list();
    for ( User event : records ) {
        System.out.println( "Records (" + event.getName + ") );
    }

    return records;
 }
```

**Update**

This is my attempt to declare the result object as List.  Does the method have to be an object instead of ?

```
public List<User> getRecords(User ent){
     String sql = "select "
                + " usr.name, usr.address "                 
                + " from User usr"           
                + " where usr.id = '1' ";

       Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();
       List<Object[]> resultList = this.getSession().createQuery(sql).list();

       // Place results in map
       for (Object[] items: resultList) {
          results.put((String)items[0], (String)items[1]);
          results.toString();
       }
       return (List<User>) results;
```

Comment: Try `List<User> records = (List<User>)this.getSession().createQuery(sql).list();`

Comment: Tried this but still get the same ClassCastException

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but... [SQL Transformers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3937519/2387977) may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a DTO class to the SELECT clause like this:

```
List<UserDTO> resultList = this.getSession().createQuery("""
    select
        new my.package.UserDTO(usr.name, usr.address)
    from User usr
    where usr.id = :userId
    """)
.setParameter("userId", userId)
.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read the complete object:

```
String sql = " from User usr"           
            + " where usr.id = '1' ";
```

Or declare the result object as `List<Object[]>`

Comment: Jens, reading the complete object works fine.  Thanks.  However I need to get specific columns so I'm attempting to declare the result object as List<Object>  Does this mean I have to change the return type to be an object instead of returning User records?

Comment: @Sunny You can also use the List<User> as return type. But you have to map it by your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **generic**(I assure you are using **java 1.5** and above) and and one you get result, you do type check and downcast to desired type.

Answer (score 0):

If You don't want to read the complete object you have to use Criteria and Projection on specific properties.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950718/how-to-return-an-entity-with-chosen-columns-using-criteria) answer it will help