# HQL Projection creates an issue

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I added a projection in my query and it created a query like...

See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626761/hibernate-criteria-query-to-get-specific-columns)

```
select
    this_.TEMPLATE_ID as y0_,
    this_.TEMPLATE_NAME as y1_,
    this_.CREATE_DATE as y2_,
    this_.UPDATE_DATE as y3_,
    this_.STATUS_CODE as y4_,
    this_.USER_ID as y5_,
    this_.UPDATED_BY as y6_,
    this_.CATEGORY_ID as y7_,
    this_.PRACTICE_ID as y8_ 
from
    templates this_ 
inner join
    user user1_ 
        on this_.USER_ID=user1_.USER_ID 
inner join
    template_categories category2_ 
        on this_.CATEGORY_ID=category2_.CATEGORY_ID 
where
    y4_=? 
    and y8_=? 
    and y5_ in (
        ?, ?
    ) 
order by
    y1_ asc limit ?
```

And now issue is like.. `Unknown column 'y4_' in 'where clause'` and same error for y8_ , y5_ means for all where close it gave an error.

I modified it to Query like ...

```
select
    this_.TEMPLATE_ID as y0_,
    this_.TEMPLATE_NAME as y1_,
    this_.CREATE_DATE as y2_,
    this_.UPDATE_DATE as y3_,
    this_.STATUS_CODE as y4_,
    this_.USER_ID as y5_,
    this_.UPDATED_BY as y6_,
    this_.CATEGORY_ID as y7_,
    this_.PRACTICE_ID as y8_ 
from
    templates this_ 
inner join
    user user1_ 
        on this_.USER_ID=user1_.USER_ID 
inner join
    template_categories category2_ 
        on this_.CATEGORY_ID=category2_.CATEGORY_ID 
where
    this_.STATUS_CODE=1
    and this_.PRACTICE_ID=1 
    and this_.USER_ID in (
        1, 2
    ) 
order by
    y1_ asc limit ?
```

and it worked. But I don't know how to modify it in HQL?

Comment: provide your exact Java code of projection

Comment: reffer this link -->  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84644/hibernate-query-by-example-and-projections

Comment: Thanks @Pradeep your link gave me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply used this.fieldName and issue resolve.
See post

> [Hibernate Query By Example and Projections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84644/hibernate-query-by-example-and-projections)